# Need help getting divs to fill entire text and screen area

Tags: html, screen, transparent, fill

So, I'm working on coding my first site. It's a lot of googling for hours, then putting down the code, but I'm struggling through it, and enjoying it. However, I have a problem I've been unable to solve.

I am trying to get a div that fills the whole page by default, but that also expands when text goes past the "100%" height. I've tried using the two seperate divs to accomplish it, and it's worked. However, I am trying to use a semi-transparent div, meaning I can't stack two on top of each other, or else part of it (the "height:100%") becomes solid, while the other part (the div that expands to fit the text) is still semitransparent. Is there any way to make a div fill the remainder of the page from the point it starts? So that that way it could fill from the bottom of the 100% height to the rest of where the text fits? I would just space it using a margin-top characteristic, but the pages need to be elastic and be able to grow with the content. Sorry if this doesn't make sense.. It's hard for me to explain it without examples and being able to point. Haha.

Comment: Some sample code would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the CSS property you would want to use in this instance is min-height. If you give an element a min-height, even if the content is smaller than the min-height, it will render at that value. If the content is larger than the min-height, then it will expand to fit the size of the content.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help. I can't believe it was that simple. I've heard about the min-height property, but never actually thought about it. Thanks so much.